# Few doubts about pointers in C

Tags: c

1) to initialize a pointer I use:

```
int number, *Pnumber;
    Pnumber=&number;
    number=10;
```

Am I doing this right?

what about:

```
int *Pnumber;
*Pnumber=10;
```

When I compile it, I get:

> RUN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 858ms)

btw. do I need to use free(Pnumber) to free the memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Am I doing this right?

Yes, you are.

> what about:

```
  `int *Pnumber;  
   *Pnumber=10;`
```

`Pnumber` is an unitialized pointer. Dereferencing this pointer leads to an undefined behavior. `Pnumber` must point to an allocated memory (either to a variable or a dynamically allocated memory area).

> btw. do I need to use free(Pnumber) to free the memory?

As long as you don't use `malloc`, don't use `free`.

Answer (score 2):

In the first version you point the pointer Pnumber to memory that has already been allocated and thus you may change the value pointed to by the pointer. This version is correct. In the second version you never specify what is the pointer pointing to(it remains uninitialized) and thus when you try to access the memory this will cause an error. So the second version is **not** correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your first approach is right.

But this wrong:

```
int *Pnumber;
*Pnumber=10;
```

Because the pointer doesn't point to valid memory whereas in the first approach it does.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is correct

In the second you are missing pointing the pointer to a memory space.

The pointer is an address so

If we have

```
int *p;
```

That means p is an address

and *p is the content of the memory address.

so the pointer should be pointed to  a memory space before you fill the memory with

```
*p = 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use a Pointer you "point a variable like you did:

```
 int number, *Pnumber;
Pnumber=&number;
number=10;
```

the advantage of the Pointer is that you save memory to your Program  so if you want to change the value of number which is an integer 32bit you can use 
     *Pnumber = 10;
here you're using integer but if you use a array of them or double or float it a lot of memory and that why it better for you to save the address of the variable in 32 bit in 32bit OS architecture  always with pointer in doesn't matter what type you'RE pointing at

Comment: number is not required to be a 32-bit integer. C is a programming language described in terms of the C abstract machine. "Abstract" means "Existing in thought or as an idea but not having a physical or concrete existence". This means that the C language is described separate from any physical or concrete OS. I suggest familiarising yourself with §5.2.4.2.1 of n1570.pdf which specifies the actual requirements of int in C.

Comment: int are either  16 bit or 32bit in c., and I think you say that because he didn't initialize the variable  ?

Comment: If you had read §5.2.4.2.1 of n1570.pdf, you'd have realised that ints aren't required to be 16 bit or 32 bit, but they must be 16 bits *or greater* in width. This includes 17 bits and 42 bits. If you don't remember the old computers that used 7 bit bytes, then you're a new kid on the block. A global adoption of unicode could result in 24-bit chars. ints would be 24 bit, 48 bit, 72 bit, or any other multiple of CHAR_BIT (which would change to 24 in this case), possibly with some padding.